# Discrete Math on Isomorphic Graphs

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I'm not sure how to show or draw that no self-complementary graphs can exist or not for the following question.

Show that no self-complementary graphs with 6 or 7 vertices can exist.

Answer (score 1):

Let $G$ be a graph and $G^c$ be its complement, and $E(G)$ the set of edges of $G$. We have that $|E(G)|+|E(G^c)|=n(n-1)/2$, which is the number of edges in the complete graph on $n$ vertices. If $G$ is self-complementary then $|E(G)|=|E(G^c)|$, so we must have $2|E(G)|=n(n-1)/2$. What happens when you plug in 6 or 7 for $n$?

Comment: In this case we get 15 and 21, but how we're going to relate this to show that no self-complementary graphs can exist??

Comment: What happens if you try to solve $2|E(G)|=15$?

Comment: Do we get |E(G)| = 15/2?? I'm not sure

Comment: Based on what $|E(G)|$ represents in a graph, is it allowed to not be a whole number?

Comment: but does that mean it can exist?? if so how?

Comment: Can a graph have 7.5 edges?

Comment: Oh OK , now i think i got it. That's how we show that no self-complementary graphs can exists

Comment: because edges with 7.5 can't be a graph!